# Google cloud storage API - Merge data to existing

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have some data sets in Google cloud storage. I could find how I can append more data to this dataset. But if I want to merge the data set(Insert else update), how do I do it?

I have one option of using Hive - Insert overwrite. Is there any other better option?

Is there any option with Google cloud storage API itself?

Comment: I have set of delimited files. Not exactly comma separated. But ^ separated files.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this could be helpful: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/compose

```
Objects: compose

Concatenates a list of existing objects into a new object in the same bucket.
```

Comment: Please notice it cannot concatenate more than 32 objects and does it on a server. This means you have to compose batches on 32 objects recursively which is pain in the google object

Answer (score 0):

GCS treats your objects (files) as blobs, there are no in-built GCS operations on the text in your objects. There is an easier way to do the same as you are doing though.

[App-engine hosted MapReduce](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/dataprocessing/mapreduce_library#job_settings) provides in-built adapters to work with GCS. You can find the example code in [this repo](http://appengine-mapreduce.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/java/example/).

Comment: Thanks Ashish. Can you help me understand? You mean, I can write a Mapreduce program which will merge the data sets? And the mapreduce program could point to GCS location. Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: Is there any option where I can use sqoop? Can I use sqoop for merging two datasets in Google cluster and output the resultant data into google cluster?

Comment: not really sqoop like. appengine will run a webserver for you which can take a request with parameters and in you can run the job insode it accordingly. you can find a code-sample here:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/mapreduce_library#Python_Features_and_capabilities